# Wilcoxon rank sum calculator

Tags: statistics

I have been looking for an online resource for calculating the p-value based on the sample sizes and the Wilcoxon rank statistic and the alternative hypothesis. All the calculators I find online require that you enter the data, but I am looking for something that given the Wilcoxon rank statistic (or Mann Whitney), the sample sizes of the groups and the alternative hypothesis can give you the P-value. This would be useful especially for the Siegel Tukey Test since I was also unable to find an online resource for that as well.

Thanks